# TypeScript: How can I pass narrowing types through a series of chained functions?

Tags: typescript

I have a series of chained functions through which I'd like to narrow types based on a nested key structure. The code below (without the nested functions) infers types without any issue:

```ts
const Keys = <const> {
    'KeyOne': {
        'SubKey1': '...',
        'SubKey2': '...'
    },
    'KeyTwo': {
        'SubKey3': '...',
        'SubKey4': '...'
    }
}

type Key = keyof typeof Keys;
type SubKey<K extends Key> = keyof typeof Keys[K];

let keyOne : Key = 'KeyOne';
let subKeyOne : SubKey<typeof keyOne> = 'SubKey1';
```

However when I extrapolate this into a series of nested functions, attempting to pass any value into the returned (second) function results in the error `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

```ts
const Keys = <const> {
    'KeyOne': {
        'SubKey1': '...',
        'SubKey2': '...'
    },
    'KeyTwo': {
        'SubKey3': '...',
        'SubKey4': '...'
    }
}

type Key = keyof typeof Keys;
type SubKey<K extends Key> = keyof typeof Keys[K];

function foo(f: Key){
    return function bar(b: SubKey<typeof f>){
        //...etc.
    }
}

foo('KeyOne')('SubKey1') //Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

How can I pass down type information through each nested function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foo()` function has the `f` parameter of type `Key`, and `SubKey<Key>` is `never`.  Instead, you should make `foo()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a type parameter `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Key` and have `f` be of type `K`.

---

First: `SubKey<Key>` is `never`:

```
type Oops = SubKey<Key> // never
```

That's because [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) is [*contravariant*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) in the type it operates on.  In particular, `keyof (A | B)` evaluates to `(keyof A) & (keyof B)`, so the only keys `keyof (A | B)` will give you are the keys which are *definitely* known to be present in a value of type `A | B`.   That is, you will only get keys common to every member of the union.  It is not considered type safe to allow you to access a member of an object if you don't know if that object has such a member.

In your example, `(typeof Keys)[Key]` is the following union type:

```
type TypeofKeysKey = typeof Keys[Key];
/* type TypeofKeysKey = {
    readonly SubKey1: "...";
    readonly SubKey2: "...";
} | {
    readonly SubKey3: "...";
    readonly SubKey4: "...";
} */
```

As that union has no common keys, `SubKey<Key>` is `never`.  And thus the `bar()` function cannot safely accept any input.  In some sense, the compiler can't tell the difference between

```
foo("KeyOne")
```

and

```
foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "KeyOne" : "KeyTwo")
```

Certainly it would be dangerous to allow the latter to accept any input.  If we want the compiler to tell the difference between those two calls, we need to allow it to infer a narrower type for `f` based on what you pass in.

---

Enter generics:

```
function foo<K extends Key>(f: K) {
  return function bar(b: SubKey<K>) {
    //...etc.
  }
}
```

or, depending on how deep "etc" goes:

```
function foo2<K extends Key>(f: K) {
  return function bar<S extends SubKey<K>>(b: S) {
    return Keys[f][b];
  }
}
```

Anytime you might care about which particular member of a union is selected, you should consider using a generic type parameter that extends said union.

Let's see how this works:

```
foo('KeyOne')('SubKey1') // okay
foo('KeyTwo')('SubKey4') // okay
foo('KeyOne')('SubKey4') // error!
```

Nice! The compiler is now happy with you.  When you call `foo('KeyOne')`, the compiler infers `"KeyOne"` for type `K`:

```
// function foo<"KeyOne">(f: "KeyOne"): (b: "SubKey1" | "SubKey2") => void
```

And when you call `foo('KeyTwo')`, it infers `"KeyTwo"` for type `K`:

```
// function foo<"KeyTwo">(f: "KeyTwo"): (b: "SubKey3" | "SubKey4") => void
```

And in each case the returned function accepts the keys from the selected property of `typeof Keys`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUwJ4RgXhgbwFAxgckSQHkwF8AuLXPAgZQFcAjIgRkoIhAFsEA3AIYAbdgBoaefIxbIATB3xdegofJoBfcZKIAVAO4gOOWvWZEAzAqX9hlrbSlnkAFis8bQ1xuzqYA1KCQUADc2NhQSAAOCPDI6DAA1sggAGYwEdGpsSihGTHSRAA8cDAIAB5QCGAAJqhEAHzxSUhZeVlEEADacAC6oeFRMTqDqR1E8W1pHd3IfdgA9ABU6YMww5kpY3EYxrQATggC1eBCSDAFyKxUAEQAdPfXoSYHRydnF0iyN-e3jz4wAB9qM9DscwKdzk4kOZvg8nvtQW9ITIkM5Yb9Qr5FvMwnkYMQQJFUBgPsVkI15vMYGQ+Ag9mEUgwwMAoABLcAwFIgEDFUoVKq1bL1AAUKSocAAlMCYAcoAw9mBOUyWezFUwBHthUwqKS4PUpbs8JSYD9vOoGcq2RyuSBZLzypUanVyaLxQaaLL5YrGcyrWqNYU6HzHYLdfURdrzu6QXKFdkuikep0mHM8ObzbgbcLCMhSOQJdmPuwpcaQAkBEhcMafSrrdzCtciHnriKxTBG7myNcJVQtTci9dAe2PrJu+hGnwQKzqpnudndAZ8AXHCjXCWqWWK1WqTW-Zz6x2kPoQC3Xe2FyeezA+8OoeZB0Drh9nGO0BOpzP9yB55384WoWuMDGnSewgHsACEMDYEAA)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Fairly new to TypeScript and this was enlightening.